# Why would wolfram, numpy, and c++ eigen all find different eigenvectors/values for this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

the matrix in question is:

```
[[ 0.814442, -1.276283,  0.075609],
 [-1.276283,  2.000018, -0.118485],
 [ 0.075609, -0.118485,  0.007019]]
```

---

np.linalg.eig returns 
eigenvalues: [ -4.440892e-16   2.821479e+00   4.524956e-17]

```
 [[-0.843411 -0.537269 -0.046606]
 [-0.536328  0.841935  0.029411]
 [ 0.031773 -0.049878  0.99848 ]]
```

Eigen::Eigensolver (in c++) returns
eigenvalues: [  2.129351e-16   2.821479e+00   4.515928e-17]

```
[[-0.843411, -0.537269,  0.11146 ],
 [-0.536328,  0.841935,  0.129497],
 [ 0.031773, -0.049878,  0.985296]]
```

(specifically, the last column is different)

In an attempt to pinpoint which program was causing the issue, I turned to wolframalpha online and input the following:

```
eigenvalues [[ 0.814442, -1.276283,  0.075609], [-1.276283,  2.000018, -0.118485], [ 0.075609, -0.118485,  0.007019]]
```

And the result I received was

eigenvalues: { -5.416890278223673*^-7,2.82148, 4.1498287169125206*^-7}

```
{{0.438201, 0.329184, 0.836432},
{0.537269, -0.841935, 0.0498778},  
{0.72064, 0.427532, -0.545797}}
```

which... did nothing to resolve in favor of either of the previous results...

Are the disparate values in the matrices caused by rounding differences in the eigenvalues, or is something weirder going on? There also seems to be some shuffling around axes... How can I determine which of these answers is "correct" or at least "most" correct?

Answer (score 3):

Two of your eigenvalues are equal to $0$ (within machine precision).

The differences you're seeing in eigenvalues are due to roundoff error.  I think the difference in eigenvectors is because there is an entire two dimensional subspaces of eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: if so, wouldn't the eigenvector for the nonzero eigenvalue be the same across all the possible calculations? but instead the Z value of the vector with eigenvalue 2.82 is:  0.029411 in numpy,  0.129497 in eigen, and  0.0498778 in wolfram. Is Z an independent value somehow?

Comment: For np.linalg.eig and eigensolver, the eigenvectors are stored in the columns of the output array, not in the rows.  Also, you can scale an eigenvector, and it will still be an eigenvector for the same eigenvalue.  So you have perfect agreement.